# I have installed all the pre-requisites - python3(3.8.2), pip3, php, wget. Still couldn't not launch HiddenEye.py. facing the following issue

Tags: github

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./HiddenEye.py", line 25, in <module>
    verCheck()
  File "/home/kali/Downloads/HiddenEye-master/Defs/Checks.py", line 69, in verCheck
    print('{1}[{0}^{1}] {0}Failed To Get Update [Status:{1}{3}{0}]\n'
     .format(GREEN, RED, DEFAULT))
IndexError: Replacement index 3 out of range for positional args tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using outdated(Legacy) version of [HiddenEye](https://github.com/DarkSecDevelopers/HiddenEye).

Try to install latest version of HiddenEye by following official instructions or give us more details to improve your question.